# How to run a batch file keeping the console window hidden?

Tags: batch-file, inno-setup

I want to start my successfully installed Java program after the installation finished. I know how to do it in principle:

```
[Run]
FileName: "{app}\LaunchApp.bat"; Description: {cm:LaunchApp}; Flags: nowait postinstall skipifsilent
```

LaunchApp.bat:

```
start javaw -jar  MyJar.jar Main
```

This way, the console window pops up for a short while, which is not very nice. Using links, this can be avoided. However, I don't seem to be able to execute a link created in the `[Icon]` in the `[Run]` section.

Any suggestions how to solve this?

Comment: As it's the batch file/command interpreter that is showing the window, you should fine a way to stop that appearing (as it will do the same when run manually). To hide it in Inno, use `runhidden` as TLama says.

Comment: That's for your answer! I'm doing this by creating symbolic links! This way, the command prompt does not show up. As mentioned in my question, I couldn't run a symbolic link in the [Run] section

Comment: erm, symbolic links are very different to shortcuts/lnk files.

Comment: Sorry, I meant shortcuts/lnk files of course...

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try to add the [`runhidden`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_runsection.htm#runhidden) flag. From the reference:

> If this flag is specified, it will launch the program in a hidden
>   window. Never use this flag when executing a program that may prompt
>   for user input.

So this should resolve your question:

```
[Run]
FileName: "{app}\LaunchApp.bat"; Description: {cm:LaunchApp}; Flags: nowait postinstall runhidden skipifsilent
```

Answer (score 1):

You could avoid the batch file altogether and run `java.exe` with the appropriate parameters.
This won't help the window appearing when the user runs the batch file normally though.